# SQL- Need query to find all childs for a Master when Master may consist of other Master and child both

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Before posting the question i will explian the concept.
We have a main bundle which comprises of small bundles and few services.
The small bundles consist of services so in turn Manin bundle is set of services. 
Eg. We have a bundle B1 consisting of services like S1, S2 and another bunde B2 consisting of S3, S4, S5 services. Then their is a Main Bundle B3 which consist of B1, B2 and S6. 
So my table Ser_Bun_Relation has below data for that bundle:

```
Bundle_ID      SERVICE_ID       TYPE 
   B1            S1            Service
   B1            S2            Service
   B2            S3            Service
   B2            S4            Service
   B2            S5            Service
   B3            B1            Bundle
   B3            B2            Bundle
   B3            S6            Service
```

Other bundles in the table are also there so part of table data looks like below:

```
Bundle_ID      SERVICE_ID       TYPE 
   B1            S1            Service
   B1            S2            Service
   B2            S3            Service
   B2            S4            Service
   B2            S5            Service
   B3            B1            Bundle
   B3            B2            Bundle
   B3            S6            Service
   B5            S11           Service
   B6            S8            Service
   B6            S9            Service
   B7            S10           Service
   B7            S12           Service
   B8            B6            Bundle
   B8            B7            Bundle
   B8            S13           Service
```

Now what i need is that for a bundle i need to list all services associated with it, for small bundles and Main bundle too. My result should be

```
   Bundle_ID     SERVICE_ID     
    B1            S1           
    B1            S2           
    B2            S3           
    B2            S4           
    B2            S5           
    B3            S1           
    B3            S2
    B3            S3
    B3            S4
    B3            S5           
    B3            S6           
    B5            S11          
    B6            S8           
    B6            S9           
    B7            S10          
    B7            S12          
    B8            S8           
    B8            S9           
    B8            S9 
    B8            S10
    B8            S12 
    B8            S13      

   How can achieve this result
```

Comment: Check out hierarchical queries: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm or https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/hierarchical-queries

Answer (score 0):

```
with data (b, s, l) as(
  select 'B1',            'S1',            'Service' from dual union all
  select 'B1',            'S2',             'Service' from dual union all
  select 'B2',            'S3',             'Service' from dual union all
  select 'B2',            'S4',             'Service' from dual union all
  select 'B2',            'S5',             'Service' from dual union all
  select 'B3',            'B1',             'Bundle' from dual union all
  select 'B3',            'B2',             'Bundle' from dual union all
  select 'B3',            'S6',             'Service' from dual union all
  select 'B5',            'S11',            'Service' from dual union all
  select 'B6',            'S8',             'Service' from dual union all
  select 'B6',            'S9',             'Service' from dual union all
  select 'B7',            'S10',            'Service' from dual union all
  select 'B7',            'S12',            'Service' from dual union all
  select 'B8',            'B6',             'Bundle' from dual union all
  select 'B8',            'B7',             'Bundle' from dual union all
  select 'B8',            'S13',            'Service' from dual 
  order by 1,2
)
,
service_lkp (b, s) as
(
select b, s from data 
-- find all services for which the bundle is included in service
where s like 'S%' and b in (select s from data)
)
,
cte (b, s, s1) as 
(
  select b, s, s from data
  union all 
  select cte.b, serv.b, serv.s 
  from 
    cte 
    join 
    service_lkp serv 
    on (cte.s = serv.s and cte.s like 'B%')
)
select b, s1 from cte order by 1, 2;
```